# jQuery IE7 / IE8: Bind method events order bug?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

Here is sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/ewzHu/2/

```
<input id="testing" />

$('#testing').bind('change keydown',function(e){
    $('body').append('<br />'+e.type);
});
```

Triggers two change events instead of one in IE only when **ENTER** button is pressed and does not triggers keydown.

If i change the order of bindings like that:

```
$('#testing').bind('keydown change',function(e){
    $('body').append('<br />'+e.type);
});
```

Everything seems to be ok.

It looks like a bug, but i'm not so experienced.

Thanks ;)

Comment: There's not really much of a standard for things like this, though the HTML5 spec may codify some behaviors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a bug.  I tested this in Firefox, Chrome, IE9, IE8, and IE7 and here are the results I got:

- Firefox Fired: keydown, then a change.
- Chrome Fired: keydown, then a change.
- IE9 Fired: one Keydown Only
- IE7/8 Fired: two changes

Gotta love browser inconsistencies!  I try not to rely on things like this being in the same order.  Another option is to wrap it, or fix it, to eat the unneeded event, if it's important.

Comment: Maybe this have been fixed in 1.6.1+? I'll check in a moment.

Comment: Doesn't look like 1.6.1 changed anything.  Same happening on my end.

Comment: Erm... offtopic. Sheldon? Sheldon Cooper :D

Comment: /sigh Yeah, my wife thinks that's funny too. :)